# Как получить название метода из функции

Tags: java-8, рефлексия

```
Function<Car,String> function = Car::getTitle;
```

как из `function` получить стрингу `"getTitle"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете получить имя используя ссылку на метод. Когда вы присваиваете ссылку объекту функционального интерфейса, этот объект создаётся классом `java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory`, который в свою очередь только генерирует ссылку на адрес, в этом месте имя метода и метаинформация теряется.